# Conversão UnixTime para outro formato

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código `PHP`:

```
1 $timestamp = $stuMessage->unixTime;
2 fwrite($fh, "timestamp: ".$timestamp."\r\n");
3 $data = gmdate("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
4 $data2 = gmdate("Y-m-d", 1541421652);
5 fwrite($fh, $data. "\r\n");
6 fwrite($fh, $data2. "\r\n");
```

Na linha 4 eu tenho o retorno normal da data passando aquele valor do Unix que é o mesmo valor que está sendo atribuído à variável $timestamp.

Porém na linha 3 eu recebo um retorno em branco, sem nada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como é gerado esse valor unixTime, pode ser que ele esteja chegando como uma string e o parâmetro $timestamp não esteja sendo aceito pela função gmdate().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O valor unixTime está chegando como string, e o parâmetro $timestamp não esta sendo aceito pela função gmdate(). Converta para número e passe como parâmetro para a função.